# Filtering files in directory with regex.match using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, puppeteer

I'm having issues with regex.match not matching filenames which do match when I test them individually in an online checker https://regex101.com

Can anyone spot the problem in code below?

Q: Should I be using regex.**test** instead of match? If yes, how do I create the regex when it contains variables?

It should match all files starting with: **ES_(Stay) True - Lars Eriksson**

**List of files and directory** in path found by fs.readdirSync:

```
.DS_Store
ES_(Stay) True - Lars Eriksson (22).mp3
ES_(Stay) True - Lars Eriksson (22).mp3.crdownload
ES_(Stay) True - Lars Eriksson.mp3
ES_(Stay) True - Lars Eriksson.mp3.crdownload
Other - File (22).mp3
Other - File (22).mp3.crdownload
Other - File.crdownload
Other - File.mp3
originals
```

The regex converts to:

```
/^(ES_\(Stay\) True - Lars Eriksson(?: \([0-9]+\))?.mp3(?:.crdownload?)?)$/
```

**Puppeteer script:**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {

function escapeRegex(string) {
    return string.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
}

let path = '/path/to/files/';
let title = 'ES_(Stay) True';
let artist = 'Lars Eriksson';

title = escapeRegex(title);
artist = escapeRegex(artist);

let regex = `/^(${title} - ${artist}(?: \\([0-9]+\\))?\.mp3(?:\.crdownload?)?)$/`;
console.log(regex);

fs.readdirSync(path)
    .filter(f => {
        regex.match();
    })
    .map(f => {
        console.log(f);
    });

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to convert string to regex you should use `RegExp()` not just use it as string for example

```
let regex = new RegExp(`^(${title} - ${artist}(?: \\([0-9]+\\))?\.mp3(?:\.crdownload?)?)$`, 'gi');
console.log(regex);
```

- also you are used `regex.match()` what do you expect to match when there's nothing to match you are trying to match the regex with nothing it's should to be

```
f.match(regex)
```

**your code should to be like that**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {

function escapeRegex(string) {
    return string.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
}

let path = '/path/to/files/';
let title = 'ES_(Stay) True';
let artist = 'Lars Eriksson';

title = escapeRegex(title);
artist = escapeRegex(artist);

let regex = new RegExp(`^(${title} - ${artist}(?: \\([0-9]+\\))?\.mp3(?:\.crdownload?)?)$`, 'gi');
console.log(regex);

let file = fs.readdirSync(path),
matched = file.filter(f => f.match(regex))
console.log(matched)
})();
```

**Result**

```
0: "ES_(Stay) True - Lars Eriksson (22).mp3"
1: "ES_(Stay) True - Lars Eriksson (22).mp3.crdownload"
2: "ES_(Stay) True - Lars Eriksson.mp3"
3: "ES_(Stay) True - Lars Eriksson.mp3.crdownload"
```

Comment: This still doesn't seem to match the filenames. When I the regex on https://regex101.com it matches the variations ok.

Comment: I edited the question and added matched data on it

Comment: And also your regex101 is empty )':

Comment: Do you know of an inbuilt function to escape strings for regex instead of using the custom escapeRegex(string) function?

Comment: I think there's no built-in function in js to do that you can search for library to do that another way you can convert characters to hex instead and use them you can try this function ```function toHex(str) { 
 let text = ''; 
 for(let i in str) { 
  text += "\\x"+ str[i].charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase(); 
 }
 return text 
}``` - usage like `escapeRegex` > `toHex("str")`